# How to list..only the Field names for a group of files in a folder?

Tags: qgis, python

I am having...for eg, 27 files in a folder (may be a shp or tab). Is it possible to list the **Field_Names (ID, Type, Date, Allotment, etc..) alone**  of all those 27 files in a csv format or xls format?

Comment: It would be easy with GDAL on a Unix command line, is that an option for you?

Comment: @BradHards Sorry mate...We are working in windows platform.

Comment: Python with GDAL available?

Comment: QGIS ships with GDAL-enabled python, as far as i know. So fire away that GDAL code!

Comment: @BradHards Yep..Python is available

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [an entry in the python GDAL/OGR cookbook](http://pcjericks.github.io/py-gdalogr-cookbook/vector_layers.html#get-shapefile-fields-get-the-user-defined-fields), here is a basic example of enumerating the shapefiles and dumping out the features in the zero'th layer (which is the only layer in a shapefile):

```
from osgeo import ogr
from os import listdir, linesep, path

sourcedir = "/home/bradh/ne_50m/"
csv = open("myshapefilefeatures.csv", 'w')
separator = ','

for filename in listdir(sourcedir):
    if filename.endswith(".shp"):
        print "processing: " + filename
        dataSource = ogr.Open(path.join(sourcedir, filename))
        daLayer = dataSource.GetLayer(0)
        layerDefinition = daLayer.GetLayerDefn()

        # if you want to include the filename in the output, just add something like:
        # csv.write(filename)
        # csv.write(separator)

        # This strange construction puts a separator between the features but not after the last feature
        for i in range(layerDefinition.GetFieldCount() - 1):
            csv.write(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())
            csv.write(separator)
        csv.write(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(layerDefinition.GetFieldCount() - 1).GetName())
        csv.write(linesep)

csv.close()
```

Certainly not the greatest python code of all time, but for simple cases and hopefully easy enough to understand....

Comment: Thanks a lot for your timely response. But i have to  say,i dont know anything about python and i can't figure it out what's the problem is. Indent is related to spacing between the lines/words rite ?


Python 2.7.4 (default, Apr  6 2013, 19:54:46) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on ICPL-PC004
## Type help(iface) for more info and list of methods.
from osgeo import ogr
from os import listdir, linesep, path
sourcedir = "W:/GIS/1404_My1/#Working"
csv = open("myshapefilefeatures.csv", 'U')

Comment: Sorry..after reading the input file..it showing this errors..

IndentationError: unexpected indent
            csv.write(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())
  File "<input>", line 1
    csv.write(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
            csv.write(separator)
  File "<input>", line 1
    csv.write(separator)
   ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Comment: Python is whitespace sensitive. You need to make a file that looks like the code sample I posted (including the indentation, and with the right directory and output filename which it looks like you've added), and run that in python. So if its called "shapefilefeatures.py", you'd run it in python by ```python shapefilefeatures.py```.

Comment: This is the error i am getting after i cleraed all the indentation errors.

File "<input>", line 1, in <module>

File "C:/OSGeo4W/bin/Fieldnames.py", line 21, in <module>

csv.write(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())

IOError: File not open for writing

Comment: If you still have ```csv = open("myshapefilefeatures.csv", 'w')```, then you're probably trying to run this somewhere that your user can't write to. Replace with a path that your user can write to, or run somewhere else.

Comment: Still the same. I am sure the folder is accessible to all the users. Will check it once again & reply. 

Thanks a lot man..for sparing the time. Cheers.

execfile(u'C:/OSGeo4W/bin/Fieldnames.py'.encode('mbcs'))
processing: Sampling.shp
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:/OSGeo4W/bin/Fieldnames.py", line 21, in <module>
    csv.write(layerDefinition.GetFieldDefn(i).GetName())
IOError: File not open for writing

Comment: What if you use ```csv = open(r"c:\Users\<whoever>\Documents\myshapefilefeatures.csv", 'w')```, replacing the ```<whoever>``` part with your user?

Comment: yahooooo....thank u so much man..it worked. The problem was due to user - restrictions.

One last question.... Is it possible to make this code work for any file format...like...tab,dxf... Hope it will work i if change the endswith(".shp") to (".tab"). But is it possible to read shp + tab + dxf through a single code ?

Comment: You can use multiple formats by simply adding conditions to the ```if filename.endswith(".shp"):``` line (e.g. ```if filename.endswith(".shp") or filename.endswith(".tab") or filename.endswith(".dxf"):```, many other options for coding this kind of thing, not GIS specific). Note that this will only work if there is only one layer. If you want it to work for multiple layers, you'd need to enumerate them. That might be another question though.

Comment: Sorry to bother u again... Is it possible to create a plugin sort of thing...to manually access a folder (which will eventually select all the shape files in the folder) & define a particular output folder... Coz we have more than one lakh shape files in different folders. With this code..i've to change the PATH each & every time, rite ? So is there any alternative way of doing this. 

sorry again for all this basic questions...coz...i an very much a kid in these things

Comment: I think you need another question, with a full description of what you need.